# Java jcifs set Property Author

Tags: android, kotlin, jcifs

I am using jcifs in my Kotlin App.

I want to write a File to the SMB Server.

How can i set the Filepropery "Autor" in jcifs?

Here is my Code:

```
var smbfile: SmbFile = SmbFile(path, auth)    
val smbfos = SmbFileOutputStream(smbfile)
    smbfos.write(it.readBytes())
```

Comment: `want to write a File to the SMB Server.` You do not have to supply an author for that.

Comment: @blackapps, i know but i want it. Do you know, how i can do this?

Comment: Your code would be ok without that author i think. I cannot remember that i ever used an author.

Comment: @blackapps When you open in Windows a File, you can see, who has created the File in the Fileproperties. Is it possible to set that property?

Comment: I never saw that and i dont know.